# How do I create a numerical rating system in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a **numerical** rating system in rails where users can rate a post from **1 - 10**.

I've looked on Google but I only find outdated tutorials and star rating gems which simply don't do the job for me.

Perhaps someone can point me to a gem that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby Toolbox lists several, although most are DOA.  Mongoid_ratings seemed to be the most recently updated, although you may not want to go the Mongo route.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_ratings

I would suggest building from scratch.  Heres a quick (and probably non-functional/non-secure) hack that might help get you started:

**Routes**

```
resources :articles do
  resources :ratings
end
```

**Models**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  validates_presence_of :article
  validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => 1..10
end
```

**Controllers**

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_article

  def create
    @rating = @article.ratings.new :value => params[:value]
    if @rating.save
      redirect_to article_ratings_path(@article), :notice => "Rating successful."
    else
      redirect_to article_ratings_path(@article), :notice => "Something went wrong."
    end
  end

  def update
    @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])
    @rating.update_attribute :value, params[:value]
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(parms[:article_id])
    end
end
```

**In an article view somewhere:**

```
form_for [@article,@rating] do |f|
  f.select("rating", "value", (1..10))
  f.submit "Rate this Article"
end
```

Comment: Hey man! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. The thing is I work with users as well and I need users only to be able to rate an article once. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: A complicated issue,http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise might get you started

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Letsrate gem: https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate

Works great for me.